# How to make MissingPermissions command handler formatted better?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

One of my command handlers is a MissingPermissions. The code for it is...

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! `Required Permission: {error.missing_perms}`")
```

The output is...

`@member, Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! Required Permission: ['manage_roles']`

Is there a way that the bot can remove those brackets and quotation marks? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is. [`missing_perms`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=missing_perms#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions.missing_perms) returns a list, if you want only the first role to show up use `0` index:

```py
await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! `Required Permission: {error.missing_perms[0]}`")
```

And if you want all permissions to be shown use `join()` function:

```py
await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do this! `Required Permission: {' '.join(error.missing_perms)}`")
```